# Do Forwarding Table (FIB not LFIB) have MPLS label?

Tags: mpls, cef

In my opinion, FIB doesn't have MPLS label, FIB should be populate from RIB because of CEF.
However, after I seach online and find out that some tutorial stated that FIB also contains the label just like LFIB.
[image]

[image]

However, I cannot find any label or image that contains MPLS with the command "show ip cef"

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From show ip cef 100.1.1.1,we can see that FIB do have MPLS label

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, paste the actual text instead.